# Как перехватить Ctrl-D?

Tags: c++, linux

Имеется программа на C++. Нужно в ней перехватить <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Как я понял, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> вызывает EOF. Читал про `<signal.h>`, но так перехватываются лишь обычные сигналы типа тех, что посылают <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (`SIGTSTP`, `SIGINT`). Так как перехватить <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - будь то напрямую нажатие клавиш или же посылаемый <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> сигнал?
*Сразу говорю, модулей ядра aka перехват на уровне ядра, не предлагать.*

Comment: дык, просто читать stdin и смотреть, когда очередная попытка чтения вернёт EOF…

Comment: Это часть реализации Shell, сигналы тут не причём.

Comment: Это не сигнал. Это конец файла stdin. Перехватывать конец файла нельзя, его можно лишь обнаруживать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

жаль, ранее не ответил, но все же...

я просто сделал так:

```
getline(cin, stroka);
if (cin.eof()) {
  // если поймали EOF
```